# replacing "manual file upload" with fetching files from "defined directory"

Tags: php, file-upload, xlsx

I've following code working best with uploading files using file uploader.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    require_once "simplexlsx.class.php";
    $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
    ...        
    list($cols, $rows) = $xlsx->dimension();
    ...
}
```

But, now I want to automate it one step further. I wish to get files from the defined path automatically, instead of manually uploading them. So far, I've come up with following code but its not working,

```
$dir    = '../data/';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            IF(strlen($file)>2) {
                echo $file."<br/>";
                $dirfile= "{$dir}{$file}";
                echo $dirfile;

                $filedata = file_get_contents($dirfile);

                require_once "simplexlsx.class.php";
                //$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );                
                $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('{$filedata}'); 
                ...        
                list($cols, $rows) = $xlsx->dimension();
                ...
```

I'm not sure about, what to pass to SimpleXLSX function instead of $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']. The following is not helping at all.

Before: **$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );**

After: **$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('{$filedata}');**

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: it was just not executing the code, no error. 
I've just fixed it, it was expecting the filepath as parameter. Following is the correct line, initially i was trying this but with additional single quote. 

$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX({$dirfile});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just fixed it, it was expecting the filepath as parameter. Following is the correct line, initially i was trying this but with additional single quote.

```
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX({$dirfile});
//where $dirfile = '../data/test.xlsx'
```